# AWS JavaScript SDK v3 : SignatureDoesNotMatch : The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-permissions

I'm trying to setup a node.js app that will upload files to an S3 bucket. I keep getting this error:

**SignatureDoesNotMatch : The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.**

I'm not sure what this means, but appears to be related to authentication or permissions? For simplicity sake, I'm trying this code to simply return a list of buckets:

```
import { S3Client, ListBucketsCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: "us-west-2",
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
});

try {
  const data = await s3Client.send(new ListBucketsCommand({}));
  console.log("Success", data.Buckets);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Error", err);
}
```

For the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` values, I'm using an IAM User that I setup with these steps:

- Create a new user: [Console > Identity and Access Management (IAM) > Access management > Users > Create User](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-2#/users)
- Set Permissions : [Step 2 > Set Permissions > Create Group > Permission policies > Add user to group > Create Group > Admin > Attached policies Administrator](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-2#/users/create)
- Create access key: [Local Code](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-2#/users/details/s3-uploader-user/create-access-key)

I've tried various methods of configuring the access keys using the AWS CLI, manually adding configuration profiles, and lastly directly specifying them as environment variables and passing them into the `S3Client()` constructor. If I use the AWS Extension for VS Code and connect with my local profile using `AWS: Connect to AWS > Profile:s3-uploader-user` I can see the buckets listed under the US West (Oregon) > S3 > test-bucket. I can use the upload button in the UI to upload images. This confirms that I have sufficient permissions to upload files. In my code, I've logged the value's of the env variables to make sure they're set correctly when the s3client.send() command is invoked.

Comment: There is no need to hard code creds into your AWS JavaScript V3 app like this. Refer to the DEV Guide here for more details... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials.html

Comment: Some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903462/aws-cli-listing-s3-buckets-gives-signaturedoesnotmatch-error-using-iam-user-cred). Check the secret access key is correct (e.g. it corresponds to the access key and there's no copy/paste error) and the client is time-synced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to say, the issue was I had setup a script to read from secrets in my container that wasn't working properly and it was blanking out the value of `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. While I understand specifying the key/secret directly in the code is not best practice, it's good to know that it works.